# Why does decomposing homography matrix need camera intrinsics?

Tags: matlab, opencv, computer-vision, homography

Both opencv and matlab have the function `decomposeHomographyMatrix`. This requires the homography matrix, H, and the camera intrinsic, K. I dont understand why it needs K?

Each of these function implementations reference "Malis" (https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/inria-00174036/document). On page 7 it talks about the intrinsic matrix K but then never uses it. It doesn't seem like it is necessary?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I understand the document you linked ("Deeper understanding of the homography decomposition for vision-based control"). If I am wrong, please correct me.

**DecomposeHomographyMat needs K to compute euclidean homography H from projective homography G.**

H = K_inv * G * K (Formula2)

R, t and n will be computed from euclidean homography matrix (Formula 3).

Opencv function decomposeHomographyMat **assumes to get a projective homography matrix as an input** (not euclidean)!
Notice that in the document you linked, the projective homography matrix is called G (not H!), while an euclidean homography matrix is called H.

**Projective homography matrix** is computed based on the vectors **p** - image coordinates of the points. (pixels)

alfa_p * p_c = G * p_star

**Euclidean homography matrix** is computed based on the vectors **m** "normalized projective coordinates of the points viewed from the camera pose" (e.g. meters).

alfa_m * m_c = H * m_star

Where: -c - current frame; _d - desired frame;  alfa - just scale factors

The relationship between image and projective coordinates is:

m = K_inv * p

K - matrix of the camera intrinsic parameters; K_inv - inverse of the matrix K

To be even more clear:

p_c = G * p_star

-> K * K_inv * p_c = G * K * K_inv * p_star

->  K * m_c = G * K * m_star

-> m_c = K_inv * G * K * m_star

-> m_c = H * m_star

Remember that:
K_inv * K = I - identity matrix

Answer (score 0):

Well, you must know K in order to find R,T. Formula (1) in your reference shows this clearly (the homography G is given in your case and you are looking for the camera pose R,T). There is no way to solve for R,T without knowing K.

Whether K is used later depends on what you are going to do with the pose. If you are going to project 3D landmarks to images, you must know K for that too.

Not sure if I am telling you anything new...